# use jest mock to run async function in isolation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jestjs

async await jest mock http request in node.jest

```
I can write my test like so
it('works with async/await', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const data = await user.getUserName(4);
  expect(data).toEqual('Mark');
});
```

but getUserName will be executed and it hit my backend and database, how to mock the function so that my test can be run in isolation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually mock the `user` object. I don't have full context but you probably have something like `const User = require('../user.js')`. So with jest you can mock this by doing

```js
jest.mock('../user.js')
```

jest.mock accepts also a callback where you can add there your own implementation but I prefer having a seperate **mocks** folder where you can keep your own implementation of the mock as it might make the tests a bit more cluttered.

You can check how it's used [here](https://github.com/gkampitakis/fastify-template-server/blob/5b211484c6ac178e41773d11454145092072129b/src/server.spec.ts#L5) where you call jest.mock and then the [mock implementation](https://github.com/gkampitakis/fastify-template-server/blob/master/__mocks__/fastify.ts).

Comment: really? mock the entire user object?

Comment: You can mock only the method you need I find it more clean as later you can use it to other tests as well or have some more complex logic.